# I will go home/ I am going to go home =? I am going home

Tags: grammar

If I remember correctly, **Be going to** is used to talk about future plans, so in this case I believe I can replace it with "will".

Now, my question is I want to know whether these sentence below are equivalent or not. And tell me if there's a mistake.

1. Alex is going home at 4 o'clock.
2. Alex is going to go home at 4 o'clock/Alex will go home at 4 o'clock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three verb tenses here, and they're all different in function.

*Present continuous for future plans* means the decision is made, and there's every reason to believe it will happen. "*Alex **is going** home at 4 o'clock*" means Alex has definite plans to go home at 4:00, with no intention of changing them.

*"will"-future* or *"simple future"* are guesses about the future without any evidence that it's right, or dependent on a condition. "*Alex **will go** home at 4 o'clock*" is just a guess as to what will happen. It's often accompanied by a hedge, like "I think" or "I guess", or by a condition, like, "If I tell her to, Alex will go home at 4 o'clock".

*"be going to"-future* is the general future form of English. Almost every sentence about the future *could* use this form, though it's not always the most natural. So, *Alex **is going to go** home at 4 o'clock* could mean Alex has a definite plan, or that it's just a random guess, or somewhere in between.